# How to convert special characters in a string to unicode?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, special-characters

I couldn't find an answer to this problem, having tried several answer here combined to find something that works, to no avail.
An application I'm working on uses a users name to create PDF's with that name in it. However, when someones name contains a special character like `"Yağmur"` the pdf creator freaks out and omits this special character.
However, when it gets the unicode equivalent (`"Ya&#287;mur"`), it prints `"Yağmur"` in the pdf as it should.

How do I check a name/string for any special character (regex = `"[^a-z0-9 ]"`) and when found, replace that character with its unicode equivalent and returning the new unicoded string?

Comment: This is not what regex is for. Search for a spellchecker, spelling suggestions, or something like that.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the PDF?  There could be an encoding problem here.

Comment: When you say "Unicode equivalent" you really mean "character entity reference". The Unicode character you want *is* ğ.

Comment: It's not a "unicode equivalent". This is an HTML/XML escape sequence. Can you show the code you are using to add that string to the PDF, and what you mean by "freaks out"?

Comment: While badly worded, and suggesting a regex solution that's probably misplaced, I believe the question is real enough. The desired function takes a proper Java `String` containing any character, and returns another string in which every non-ASCII input is replaced by its XML character entity reference. (TODO: check how `<>&;#` behave; they're ASCII but also may require substitution).

Comment: My appologies for the description, it's my first post here. I'll try to look up the code.
Also,freak out might have been a bad choice of words, as it just skips the special character,so it's being quite calm about it realy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give the solution in generic way as the frame work you are using is not mentioned as the part of your problem statement.

I too faced the same kind of issue long time back. This should be handled by the pdf engine if you set the text/char encoding as UTF-8. Please find how you can set encoding in your framework for pdf generation and try it out. Hope it helps !!

Comment: I will see if I can get this information and see if I can do something this way,

Comment: Somehow the call for the pdf generator was not explicitly done with UTF-8 encoding in this particular instance (all others did do so). After forcing UTF-8 it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One hackish way to do this would be as follows:

```
/*
 * TODO: poorly named 
 */ 
public static String convertUnicodePoints(String input) {
    // getting char array from input
    char[] chars =  input.toCharArray();
    // initializing output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // iterating input chars
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        // checking character code point to infer whether "conversion" is required
        // here, picking an arbitrary code point 125 as boundary
        if (Character.codePointAt(input, i) < 125) {
            sb.append(chars[i]);
        }
        // need to "convert", code point > boundary
        else {
            // for hex representation: prepends as many 0s as required
            // to get a hex string of the char code point, 4 characters long
            // sb.append(String.format("&#xu%04X;", (int)chars[i]));

            // for decimal representation, which is what you want here
            sb.append(String.format("&#%d;", (int)chars[i]));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you execute: `System.out.println(convertUnicodePoints("Yağmur"));`...

... you'll get: `Ya&#287;mur`.

Of course, you can play with the "conversion" logic and decide which ranges get converted.

Comment: Could you explain how the if (Character.codePointAt(input, i) < 123) statement works? 
I agree that it would be hackish, but if this is what it takes for this thing to work...

Comment: Well the API for the method is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)).  The `123` operand I compare it with is arbitrary, it represents one of the last characters in the ASCII table. You can see an ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/), for your reference.

Comment: Actually just changed it to `125`, makes more sense.